# How magic percentage is calculated (stats involved)

Tags: shadowrun-returns, shadowrun-hong-kong

I'm playing Shadowrun Returns HK for the first time as magic user. 
I don't understand how the chance to hit a person (or area of effect) is calculated.

What should I increase in my stats to increase that percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main stat that governs both spell accuracy and spell resistance is willpower.

Qi casters have a passive spell resistance ability they can slot in which can drastically lower your chance to hit.